# Diameter of Ellipse

Tags: calculus

Find the length of the diameter with the slope of 1 in the ellipse $x^2 + 3y^2 +2x-6y=0$?

My first step in solving this problem is that I differentiate the equation of ellipse

$2x + 6yy' +2 - 6y'= 0$

Substituting $1$ to $y'$

I was able to get the equation of the diameter of the ellipse

$2x + 6y - 4 = 0$

And I'm stuck. I don't know what to do next in order to get the length of the diameter. Can anyone give me a hint? Is my process correct?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: How are you defining the diameter of an ellipse?

Comment: It is a locus of the midpoint  of parallel chords that passes through the centre of the ellipse

Comment: I suggest adding the definition to your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, complete the squares to find the center of the ellipse.

Starting with $x^2 + 3 y^2 + 2 x - 6 y = 0 $ this becomes

$ (x + 1)^2 + 3 (y - 1)^2 = 4 $

So the center is $(-1, 1) $

Now the line passing through this center and having a slope of $1$ is parametrically given by

$ p(t) = p_0 + t u $

where $p_0 = (-1, 1)$ and $ u = (\cos 45^\circ , \sin 45^\circ) = ( \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ) $

Now intersect the line with the ellipse.  The equation of the ellipse can be written as

$ (r - p_0)^T Q (r - p_0) = 4 $

where $ p_0 = (-1, 1) $ and $Q = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 3 \end{bmatrix} $

Plugging in $r = p(t) $ gives us

$ t^2 u^T Q u = 4 $

Now since $u^T Q u = \dfrac{(1 + 3)}{2} = 2 $

Then $t^2 = 2 $

Thus the roots are $t = \pm \sqrt{2}$, and hence the length of the diameter $= 2 \sqrt{2} $

Comment: It’s fine, but you missed the quick way, namely to notice that the line through $(-1,1)$ of slope $1$ is $y=x+2$. Making this substitution into the original equation gives $4x^2+8x=0$, and thus the two points are $(0,2)$ and $(-2,0)$, diagonal points of a square of side-length two, so that the length of the line is $2\sqrt2$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I get it now. My assumption was wrong I thought the slope of the chords is 1.It should be the slope of the diameter.

Comment: @Lubin It's even simpler than that: we get $(x + 1)^2 + 3(x + 1)^2 = 4$ which is a miracle.

Comment: Shame on me, @TobyMak , for not seeing that. Thanks. (I do wish the problem had been a little farther-out.)

Answer (score 0):

Lexi Belle Fan's approach is valid but it overcomplicates things, as per Lubin's comment.

The line with slope $1$ passing through $(-1,1)$ is $y - 1 = x - (-1) \Rightarrow y = x + 2$. Now to find where the line intersects the ellipse, we can directly substitute into $(x+1)^2 + 3(y-1)^2 = 4$:

$$(x + 1)^2 + 3(x + 1)^2 = 4$$
$$x + 1 = ± 1$$

and so the distance between the points $(-2, 0)$ and $(0, 2)$ is $2 \sqrt{2}$, which is the length of the diameter.